# D3 Sticky Force responsive

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm struggling trying to understand how to make this graph http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558
responsive.
The problem is that I have some nodes width fixed coordinates, I'm not sure how to handle those when the browser width changes (I guess with css translate?).

Answer (score 1):

Making an svg element responsive is independent of what type of element it is, be it force-layout, line chart or other svg-based rendering.

You can leverage the [`zoom-behavior`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior) native to d3 to resize `<g>` groups. You can pragmatically call zoom-event handlers when the window is resized, in your case, you will need to resize based on the viewport sizes or other methods of retrieving the screen size.

You may also be interested in resizing your fixed-position graph (wrapped in `<g>` element) based on ratios of bounding boxes between particular parent and child svg element. You can checkout sample usages of bounding boxes [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1160929)

Comment: I tried something, but it doesn't work
`d3.select(window).on('resize', resize); 

function resize(){
 var w=$(document).width();
 var h=$(document).height();
 var z=d3.behavior.zoom(w,h);
 d3.select("svg#logograph").call(z)
}`